# Counting distinct elements from strings PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql, count

I am trying to count the elements contained in a string in the following way:

```
row  features
1    'a | b | c'
2    'a | c'
3    'b | c | d'
4    'a'
```

Result:

```
feature  count
a        3
b        2
c        3
d        1
```

I have already found a solution by finding the highest number of features and separating each feature into 1 column, so feature1 = content of feature 1 in the string, but the I have to manually aggregate the data. There must be a smart way to do this for sure as in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `regexp_split_to_table`:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(feature, E' \\| ') AS k, count(*)
FROM tab1
GROUP BY k
```

Answer (score 2):

By normalizing the data by using `unnest()` this turns into a simple `group by`

```
select trim(f.feature), count(*) 
from the_table t
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.features, '|')) as f(feature)
group by trim(f.feature)
order by 1;
```